# Open AL Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, audio, nullpointerexception, lwjgl, openal

I'm attempting to do my first test with open AL and I keep getting a null pointer error as per below:

```
Exception in thread "main"
C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\Programming Workspace\Android\RPG Test Engine\res\sounds\test1.wav
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.evylgaming.rpg.SoundManager.getSoundsFromFile(SoundManager.java:119)
at com.evylgaming.rpg.RPGMain.main(RPGMain.java:14)
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

The link you're seeing is in reference to where the error is. I wanted to ensure the file was loaded so am I doing something incorrectly?

```
package com.evylgaming.rpg;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.openal.AL;
import org.lwjgl.openal.AL10;
import org.newdawn.slick.openal.WaveData;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SoundManager {

    private File soundsFolder;
    private File[] soundFolderFiles;

    static HashMap<String, Integer> buffers = new HashMap<>();
    static HashMap<String, Integer> sources = new HashMap<>();
    static HashMap<String, float[]> sourcePositions = new HashMap<>();
    static HashMap<String, float[]> sourceVelocitys = new HashMap<>();
    static                 float[]  listenerPosition;
    static                 float[]  listenerVelocity;

    // static HashMap<String, Point> locations = new Hashmap<String, Point>();
    // AL_BUFFER, AL_POSITION, AL_PITCH, AL_GAIN

    public void playSound(int index) {
        AL10.alSourcePlay(sources.get(index));
    }

    public void stopSound(int index) {
        AL10.alSourceStop(sources.get(index));
    }

    public void pauseSound(int index) {
        AL10.alSourcePause(sources.get(index));
    }

    public void playSound(String name) {

        if(sources.containsKey(name)) {
            AL10.alSourcePlay(sources.get(name));
        } else {}

    }

    public void stopSound(String name) {
        if(sources.containsKey(name)) {
            AL10.alSourceStop(sources.get(name));
        } else {}

    }

    public void pauseSound(String name) {
        if(sources.containsKey(name)) {
            AL10.alSourcePause(sources.get(name));
        } else {}
    }

    public void setSourcePosition(int index, float x, float y, float z) {
        AL10.alSource3f(sources.get(index), AL10.AL_POSITION, x, y, z);
        System.out.println("Source at index: " + index + " set to position X:" + x + " Y:" + y + " Z: " + z);
    }
    public void setSourceVelocity(int index, float x, float y, float z) {
        AL10.alSource3f(sources.get(index), AL10.AL_VELOCITY, x, y, z);
        System.out.println("Source at index: " + index + " set to Velocity X:" + x + " Y:" + y + " Z: " + z);
    }

    public SoundManager(String fileName) {
        soundsFolder = new File(fileName);
        soundFolderFiles = soundsFolder.listFiles();
    }

    // Init for open AL
    public void getSoundsFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        int index = 0;
        try {
            AL.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            System.out.println("Open AL failed to initialize");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < soundFolderFiles.length; i++) {
            if( !buffers.containsKey(soundFolderFiles[index])) {
                WaveData soundData;

                soundData = WaveData.create(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(soundFolderFiles[index].getCanonicalPath())));

                System.out.println(soundFolderFiles[index].getCanonicalPath());
                buffers.put(soundFolderFiles[index].getCanonicalPath(), AL10.alGenBuffers());
                AL10.alBufferData(buffers.get(index), soundData.format, soundData.data, soundData.samplerate);
                sources.put(soundFolderFiles[index].getCanonicalPath(), AL10.alGenSources());

                sourcePositions.put(soundFolderFiles[index].getCanonicalPath(), new float[ ] {0, 0, 0});
                sourceVelocitys.put(soundFolderFiles[index].getCanonicalPath(), new float[ ] {0, 0, 0});

                AL10.alSourcei(sources.get(index), AL10.AL_BUFFER,buffers.get(index));
                AL10.alSource3f(sources.get(index), AL10.AL_POSITION, 0, 0,  0);
                AL10.alSource3f(sources.get(index), AL10.AL_VELOCITY, 0, 0, 0);

                soundData.dispose();
            }
            index += 1;

        }
        // Load listener
        AL10.alListener3f(AL10.AL_POSITION, 0, 0, 0);
        AL10.alListener3f(AL10.AL_VELOCITY, 0, 0, 0);

    }
```

This is what I'm using to load sounds. I have linked my main class below just in case. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: try writing something like System.err.println(soundFolderFiles[index].exists()) to make sure the file is actually where you think it is

Comment: This returns true, it does exist where I think it does, and where it should as per below. 

C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\Programming Workspace\Android\RPG Test Engine\res\sounds\test1.wav

Comment: can you mark which line is 119 in the source code you pasted?

Comment: AL10.alBufferData(buffers.get(index),soundData.format,soundData.data, soundData.samplerate);

I've tried replacing the buffers.get() with AL10.alGenBuffers() so it shouldn't be the buffer.

Comment: and youre positive soundData isnt null?

Comment: Using 

System.err.println(soundData.format);
System.err.println(soundData.samplerate);
System.err.println(soundData.data);

Output is: 
4353
44100
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=156946 cap=156946]

Comment: @radai Figured out it was buffers.get(i) returning null. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Why would AL10.alGenBuffers() return null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I needed to store the buffer and source in an int before pushing it through.

Solved by doing the following

int buffer = AL10.alGenBuffers();
int source = AL10.alGenSources();

And using these in place of the .get(index)